# Pagination in Django TemplateView

Tags: django

I have a template where I want to display a large list of data, (received from external API rather than DB).

Although I'm aware this is easily done is ListView, however as I'm not pulling data from the database, TemplateView seems the best choice but what would the best way to display the list of data and paginate it?

Currently I have:
View

```
class QuotesResultsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'site/quotes.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['quotes'] = self.request.session['quotes']['data']
        return context
```

Template:

....

```
        <div class="about">

          {% for quote in quotes %}
            <h3>Supplier:{{ quote.supplierName }}</h3>
              <div>
              <p>Annual Cost: {{ quote.newSpend }}</p>
              <p>Savings: {{ quote.newSavings }}</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-cta-primary">Proceed</button>
          {% endfor %}
        </div><!--//about-->
```

Comment: How are you retrieving this data? It doesn't look like it is in your view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still can inherit ListView and override `get_queryset()` method, which must return an iterable. This will enable you to use pagination as usually

```
class QuotesResultsView(ListView):
    template_name = 'site/quotes.html'
    paginate_by = settings.QUOTES_PER_PAGE
    context_object_name = 'quotes'

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Looks like your data is already an iterable
        # if not convert it to iterable and return
        return self.request.session['quotes']['data']
```

Don't forget to set `QUOTES_PER_PAGE` in your settings and import it in your views.py

Then in template your can use standard pagination snippet from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view).